# Responsive Web App with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

We have a responsive web application for desktop users and it is working fine. My organization also has native android app. Now, the requirement is to integrate responsive web app with native android app (using webview). Same time, we are looking to access some native features of device like capture photo from web application.

We suggested to use phonegap but don't know how we can integrate phonegap javascript api with existing web application without creating phonegap/corodova application. Idea is that, user just hit the native app button and on listener it will invoke webview with webapp url. By checking user agent we will be able to load phonegap JS api and it will be able to access native features.

Issue is that, Don't know whether it is possible or not, if yes then how we can enable phonegap api in existing web app. Desktop and mobile user will get same experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use WebView component of phonegap in your application, read documentation

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews

Comment: I read this link before but not able to understand integration point related to notification and others plugins. One more thing, I do not want to change my native app much but got free hand to change my desktop web application.